# "Compress file" in Catalina sets wrong permissions on ZIP file

Tags: macos, finder, permission, archive, zip

When zipping one or more files via Finder (Right click on file → Compress) the created the ZIP file has permissions set to `rw-------` / `600`.

When I use the `zip` command in Terminal, permissions are set as expected `rw-r--r--` / `644`.

All of this started to happen after I upgraded to Catalina last weekend.

Before, all ZIP files were created with permissions `rw-r--r--` / `644`, regardless if it was created via Finder or Terminal.

It looks like something is broken in the Finder command an/or Archive Utility.app

Do you know any fix for this?

This is really annoying, when uploading a zip file to an FTP server.   Today a client called that he can't download the file. It took me a while to figure out what happened.

**Clarification:** The question is **not** about how to fix the FTP upload. It is about how to make Finder / Archive utility behave in the in same way as before, using macOS Mojave.

Comment: Do I want to know why the local permissions are influencing the permissions on the remote?

Comment: @MarcWilson Transmit, my FTP client, seems to keep the permissions when uploading a file. I only added the FTP story to explain why this is an issue for me. Updated the question to clarify that point.

Comment: @bmike Why did you remove the catalina tag? This is a catalina specific issue?

Comment: Macos includes the Catalina tag. If you want to overload it, feel free to edit again. Dropping one of the side tags even Catalina provides better people for following the Mac tag, and Catalina already hits the searches, do what you want if you don’t trust my edit on tag usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed on 10.15.5 when archiving a file through Finder or Archive Utility. This was previously a bug.

Answer (score 4):

The Finder and Archive Utility are not broken; the change in permissions will be deliberate.

> It looks like something is broken in the Finder command an/or Archive Utility.app

## Increasing Security

Apple's security engineers will likely argue that the new user only read write permissions, `0600`, are correct and that `zip` is now wrong. Limiting default permissions is the direction macOS is heading.

### Automator or AppleScript

Instead of fighting Apple, consider creating an Automator service or AppleScript to compress your files. You can then control the final permissions of the archive.